# Change Of Basis of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following two bases of $\mathbb R_2$:
$S = \{ (1,0), (0,1)\}$ and $S′ = \{ (1,1) , (2,1) \}$.

(i) Find the change of basis matrix $P$ from $S$ to $S′$.

(ii) Find the change of basis matrix $Q$ from $S′$ to $S$.

(iii) What is the relation between $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: Show us what you've tried. These are basic questions and know the definitions is enough to solve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i)You have to find an answer to this question: "How can I write the elements of $S$ as linear combinations of element of $S'$?" The answer is your matrix $P$. For example

> $(1,0) =  (-1) \cdot (1,1) + 1 \cdot (2,1) $

Then $(-1,1)$ (the coefficients of that linear combination) forms the first column of your matrix $P$.

(ii)Analogously you are able to find the matrix $Q$: pick the vectors of $S'$ and write them as a linear combination of vectors in $S$. The coefficients give you the columns of the matrix $Q$. For example:

> $(1,1) = 1 \cdot (1,0) + 1 \cdot (0,1)$

Then $(1,1)$ is the first column of $Q$.

(iii) The relation is simple: try to compute the multiplication $PQ$, what do you get? The identity matrix. Then you conclude $P$ and $Q$ are the inverses of each other.

Comment: However, it is important that you do your own homework/exam problems. The only way to learn Mathematics is to do Mathematics. While this site will help you with make progress through problems, it is important that you say what you know, have done, etc., and not simply use the site as a solutions manual.

Comment: Despite the fact that your answer is not "complete", I wouldn't answer this sort of "questions" at all. This attracts people to pose this type of questions again and again (since it seems to work).